# How can I do something after value update in knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: classCode, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keypress: doSomething}">
```

I could not see the number that I enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [add a handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) to the observable itself:

```
viewMOdel.classCode.subscribe(function() { ... });
```